# Автообновление Python

Tags: python

**Здраствуйте, я делаю свою программу на языке Python, мне нужно сделать автообновление программы тоесть на моем сайте есть версия программы мне нужно сделать так чтобы программа следила за версией на сайте, и если версия изменится, чтобы она предложила пользователю скачать новую версию, и если он согласится чтобы она начала скачивать(мне бы хотябы чтобы она могла следить и дала юзеру знать что вышла новая версия**

Comment: Ваша попытка в виде минимального кода.

Comment: следить-то не проблема, а вот обновить - не очевидно

Comment: мне бы хотябы чтобы она могла следить и дала юзеру знать что вышла новая версия

Comment: Любой антивирус сразу заорёт на такое :) Много вирусов есть с подобным сценарием

Comment: А следить не вопрос - сделайте сервис на flask, отдающий json с номером версии, скачивайте его и сравнивайте версию с текущей. Всё.

Comment: Можете написать код пожалуйста, а то я так не понимаю

Comment: Писать за вас код - это на другие сайты. Прочитайте про Flask и про библиотеку requests, там всё очень просто. Если вы писали на питоне, ничего сложного для вас не будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf вообзе, интересно. ну, антиввирус заорет, я скажу, что все хорошо. Но все равно, непонятно, как подменить программу. Я пока тоже просто сообщаю, а вот подменять, даже не пытался

Comment: @splash58 Запустить отдельный процесс и завершить текущий код. А этот отдельный процесс пусть скопирует новую версию в файл со старой версией и опять запустит этот код. Как-то так.

Comment: @CrazyElf надо  будет попробовать, а то прога разошлась по куче людей, а алгоритм обработки постоянно корректируем :)